# Best way to create wordpress dev site on different server but when domain in use

Tags: wordpress

Looking for guidance on best practice in creating a new Wordpress website, online, when

A) I'll be hosting the site on a new server 
B) The site will need to be viewed by client online
C) The site domain is currently live, in use and must remain directed to current server (until site complete) and 
D) Current site is very old and would likely throw up endless issues if transferred to the new server.
E) No-one has access to the current server.

I'm currently looking at options around temp URL's, or just using a dev URL I use solely for builds. Then once complete and DNS redirected to the new server, Find and Replace all references of dev URL for the correct URL.

I've searched online but generally, only find answers to the queries "building site without impacting live site" or "building site locally". Not my query - "building a site online with a domain I can't use as it's in use etc".

Any guidance on this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Most of the url links in WP sites are dynamic. The main domains need changed in the wp_options table.  Your best bet is to proceed to develop the site with those standards and refrain from using hardcoded URL references throughout,  when it is time to take control of the site, purchase a host, upload files and import the database, update the urls in the wp_options table,  change the nameservers. I generally let the client know that this will probably hiccup for an hour and will likely take up to 24 to propagate the new ip. I usually hosted the clients test site on a subdomain of my own site.

Answer (score 0):

Create an edit in your machines hosts file so that the live url points to your dev server instead of the live server. When the client needs to check the progress they can temporarily update their own hosts file to check and then delete it out to go back to seeing their current site.

**Windows**
If you’re computer runs Windows, follow the instructions below:

- Press the Windows key.
- Type Notepad in the search field.
- In the search results, right-click Notepad and select Run as administrator.
- In Notepad, click File > Open
- Change the File Type in the bottom right corner to All Files instead of Txt Files
- Open the following file: c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
- Scroll to the bottom of the file and type the IP address of your dev server (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
- Press Tab
- Type the address we gave you (www.whatever.com)
- Click File > Save to save your changes.
- Close Notepad

If Mac

- Press Command & Space
- Type Terminal
- Press Enter
- Type sudo nano /etc/hosts
- Press Enter
- Type the password you use to log into your machine
- Press Enter
- Scroll to the bottom of the file
- Type the IP address of your server (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
- Press TAB
- Type the web address we gave you (www.whatever.com)
- Press Ctrl & X
- Press Y to save
- Press Enter

Comment: Thanks for the info on the Hosts file option. However, my concern with that route is that I will need to be able to view both the new site in development and the existing site simultaneously. As I will be referencing the current site a lot, copying out imagery and text etc.

Secondly, it relies on the client making changes to their hosts file every time they wish to view. Which unfortunately isn't suitable in this instance, due to the ability/IT knowledge of the client.

Comment: Ah I understand, what about just adding an A record on their current DNS to point to your new server? i.e. A > staging>  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -- everything stays the same everywhere else, its just the subdomain you've created that points to you? THat way everyone can check without issue.

Comment: Thanks again, but we don't currently have access to the domain, in order to edit DNS records. The client is currently chasing this with their existing site provider. So this option is a no-go I'm afraid. 

I think the best method, considering all the constraints, is a combination of your DNS option and as per @Danimal posted. In that, I set the URL as something different for now, like www.subdomain.anotherurlofmine.com, set up an A record linking to the new server from anotherurlofmine.com, and then prior to launch I edit the wp-config file to change the URL to the correct address. ???